# Preposition phrase serves as the subject complement

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> To hold any kind of resentment is **like** taking rat poison and waiting for the rat to die.

In the sentence, "like" is a preposition followed by gerunds. The preposition phrase "like taking rat poison and waiting for the rat to die" serves as the subject complement. Am I right?

Comment: Yours is an unusual simile (clever, though - I like it! :). Switching to something more commonplace, and standardising on a gerund form on both sides of the copula ("**is**") gives us, say, *"Robbing banks is like taking candy from a baby"*. Where again everything to the right of the word "**is**" could be called a "preposition phrase". But that utterance would *mean exactly the same* if we removed the "preposition" "**like**". Teachers love to go on about "metaphor vs simile" - but like "preposition phrase", such terminological distinctions don't usually *mean* much at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Would you mind phrasing your answer in the form of an answer? I'd love to upvote it.

Comment: @Omnidisciplinarianist: I think the "real" answer is just my first comment, but that's a bit terse. I'll post the essence of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's example is an unusual simile (clever, though - I like it! :).

Switching to something more commonplace, and standardising on a gerund form on both sides of the copula ("**is**") gives us, say,...

> *"Robbing banks is like taking candy from a baby"*

...where again everything to the right of the word "**is**" could be called a "preposition phrase". But that utterance would *mean exactly the same* if we removed the "preposition" "**like**". Teachers love to go on about "metaphor vs simile" - but like "preposition phrase", such terminological distinctions don't usually mean much at all.

---

TL;DR: OP's example does indeed feature a preposition phrase serving as the subject complement.

Comment: I have also heard "like shooting babies in a barrel," which combines the synonymous phrases "like shooting fish in a barrel" and "like stealing candy from a baby."

Comment: @user3932000: I've often heard usages like *Does the Pope shit in the woods* (facetiously combining *Do bears shit in the woods?* and *Is the Pope a Catholic?*), which would generally be considered "witty" even in relatively polite society. But I think your version is a bit beyond the pale, and might well get you some funny looks. I'd certainly say it'd be better not to promote its use among non-native speakers who might end up using it in contexts where some people might not even realise it was supposed to be amusingly witty (rather than just "sick").